# Unexpected SVA assertion behavior for a periodic signal

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Quoting from a book "Systemverilog Assertions and Functional Coverage", Ashok Mehta on page 42,

> @ (posedge clk) a |=> !a;
>   In the above sequence, let us say that variable ‘a’ changes to ‘1’ the same time
>   that the sampling edge clock goes posedge clk (and assume ‘a’ was ‘0’ before it
>   went to a ‘1’). Will there be a match of the antecedent ‘a’? No! Since a’ went from ‘0’ to ‘1’ the same time that clock went posedge clk, the value of ‘a’ sampled by clock will be ‘0’ (preponed region) and not ‘1’. This will not cause the property to trigger because the antecedent is not evaluated to be true. This will confuse you
>   during debug. You would expect ‘1’ to be sampled and the property triggered
>   thereof. However, you will get just the opposite result.
>   This is a very important point to understand because in a simulation waveform
>   (or for that matter with Verilog $monitor or $strobe) you will see a ‘1’ on ‘a’ with
>   posedge clk and would not understand why the property did not fire or why it
>   failed (or passed for that matter). Always remember that at the sampling edge, the
>   ‘previous’ value (i.e. a delta before the sampling edge in the preponed region) of
>   the sampled variable is used.

I tried to test this scenario by this Testbench. However I expected assertion to FAIL at simulation times #10, #50, #90

```
module assert_immediate();

      reg  a,b,clk;

      initial
      begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #10 clk = !clk;
      end

      initial
      begin
        a = 0;
        b = 0;
        repeat (10) @(posedge clk) a = ~a;
      end

     // always@(posedge clk) $display("a = %d at time %t \n", a, $time);

      property p1;
         @(posedge clk) a |=> !a;
      endproperty

      initial #100 $finish;

      assert property (p1) $display("Entered assert at %t \n", $time); else $display("FAIL at %t \n", $time);
      cover property (p1) $display("PASS at %t \n", $time);

endmodule
```

But when I ran on EDAPlayground using VCS, I got a different behavior

```
# KERNEL: Entered assert at                   10 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: PASS at                             10 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: Entered assert at                   50 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: Entered assert at                   50 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: PASS at                             50 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: PASS at                             50 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: Entered assert at                   90 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: Entered assert at                   90 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: PASS at                             90 
# KERNEL: 
# KERNEL: PASS at                             90
```

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: @KaranShah Expected behavior is `Entered assert at 10` and `PASS at 10` should not be printed.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. It seems like a tool bug, as the concurrent assertion samples value from the `preponed` region and hence `@10`, the sampled value of a should be `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are 2 issues there.

1. I think that there is a misconception in the implication operator. Assertion should not fail in your case. The implication allows for the right hand side expression to be true eventually. So, if `a` goes up, it will eventually go down. So, at #50 it goes down after sampled high at #30, and this cause the assertion to pass, and go to the next cycle of evaluation: #70 -> #90.

> For each successful match of the antecedent sequence_expr, the consequent property_expr isseparately evaluated. The end point of the match of the antecedent sequence_expr is the start pointof the evaluation of the consequent property_expr.

2. there is a bug in the compiler you use. There should be no assertion message at time #10. I tried it with vcs 2017.03 and it worked correctly.

also you can add this line to you code to get some debugging prints:

```
always @(posedge clk) $display("%0t a = %b", $time, $sampled(a));
```

I got these results during the simulation:

```
10 a = 0
30 a = 1
50 a = 0
Entered assert at 50
PASS at           50
70 a = 1
90 a = 0
Entered assert at 90
PASS at           90
```

Comment: So what is the solution if I want to sample `a` as '1' instead of '0' at first posedge and let the assertion trigger at `@time10ns` ?

Comment: If I would have placed my assertion in a clocking block, would default input #0 have helped me to sample `a` as 1 and not `0` at `@time10` ?

Comment: all values for assertions are sampled `before` the simulation cycle starts. So, in case of the posedge of the `clk`, the sampled value or `a` will be the one before the posedge, as described in the quote of the original post. It behaves exactly as was described there and warned about confusion during debug. So, it answers your original question. So, what exactly do you want to achieve? you might need to ask a different question though.

Comment: I just read in LRM, 3.1a v, page 232, "If there is no match of the antecedent sequence_expr, then evaluation of the implication succeeds vacuously and returns true" is that the reason display statement eecutes at @time10?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect your assertion to fail? You instructed your testbench to change `a` every `posedge` in the `initial` block so your assertion will pass when triggered (you will have a sequence of `a, !a, a, !a`) so I expect 2 assertion passes.

What I don't understand is that assertion passes @ time `10` according to your log. Your first `posedge` is @ time `10`, so the sampled value of `a` is `0` (because sampling is done before the `posedge` and your initial value of `a` is `0` accroding to the `initial` block). This value of `a` wouldn't trigger the assertion (doesn't meet assertion predecessor, i.e. left hand side of the assertion).

Comment: Haha, You are exactly asking the same question I have asked. `What I don't understand is that assertion passes @ time 10 according to your log.` Also, I didnt expect assertion to FAIL always, as I mentioned it should FAIL at @time 10, 50 and 90.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear. I don't understand why it is being "triggered". 
Assertion trigger is `a`. 

You wrote `However I expected assertion to FAIL at simulation times #10, #50, #90`. Your assertion will never fail in this testbench because of the retriggering `a` in your initial block. So, this answers your question. 

Regarding this strange behaviour @ time `10`: provide more details - strobe signals, waveform or try another simulator and compare results.Maybe VCS assumed a to be `1` @ the start of the sim (strobe and check)? Regards.

Comment: When does assertion trigger, when its antecedant matches or when its consequent matches? which initial blocks should I merge? I expected assert to fail at say 10ns because at 10ns, sampled value of a is still 0 and not '1'. So it does not trigger the antecedant.

Comment: Initially assertion is `inactive`. @ Time `10` (first `posedge`) assertion checks if  the `a` signal value matches antecedent. It does not (`a == 0`, assertion triggers on `a` which is a shorthand of `a == 1` and what I believe is the source of misunderstanding. It does not make assertion fail, it does only make assertion stay in `inactive` state. Assertion will trigger if `a == 1`. Only then, when the assertion triggers and is in `active` state it can `pass` or `fail` or be `disabled`. Disregard my comment on merging initial blocks, edited it because it wasn't a good advice.

Comment: `Fail` is my bad. So at 10ns, if assertion is `inactive`, then why does it display "Entered assert" at 10ns, because that display should be executed only when assertion is activated, right? What is the solution for this strange behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Consider another assertion message: `Entered assert at 50`. Assertion is triggered @ time `30`(`a` before time `30` is `1`, it will be sampled and assertion will be triggered). @ the next `posedge clk` (time `50`) assertion finishes with success (`pass`) and then `$display` is executed. 
So construct `assert property() <message> else <error>` will display messages at the end of the assert procedure. If you had an immediate assert, e.g. `assert(A==B) <display_message>` it will be executed at the same clock tick because immediate assert will finish @ the same clock tick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154874/discussion-between-shankhadeep-mukerji-and-raz).